# How to generate a new record based on the current new one and another one existed in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I need to generate one record when user creates one and there is another one already in the model with same or suitable data.

For example:

**models.py**

```py
class Generated(models.Model):
    stage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    group = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

and we already have a record `Generated(stage=1, group=1)`
then we create another one `Generated(stage=1, group=2)` and we need to **generate** one more record like `Generated(stage=2, group=1)`

So what's the way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `get_or_create` and a django `signal` to automatically save the alternate record. see below code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models

class Generated(models.Model):
    stage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    group = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

@receiver(post_save, sender=Generated):
def create_alternate(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    try:
       if created:
          Generate, create = Generated.objects.get_or_create(
               state=instance.group,
               group=instance.state
          )
          if create:
             Generate.save()
    except:
       print('Error creating alternate record!')
       print(e)
```

The above code will create or just get the alternate record if new record is created.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I used save() method. Do you think your way may be more correct?

Comment: I suggest you to go by may because it won't iterate the saving process infinite times & will not raise any error of `MisMatchingQuery` & duplicate records will not be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use signals for this

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Generated(models.Model):
    stage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    group = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

def gen_func(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.stage != instance.group:
        Generated.objects.create(stage=instance.group, group=instance.stage)
post_save.connect(gen_func, sender=Generated)
```

you can modify the `gen_func` based on your requirements